# how to get html strip of element from the clipboard?

Tags: html, text, clipboard, strip

There are two divs, both set to contenteditable= true.
I am typing some text in div 1 and then I am copying the text using Ctl + A and Ctl + C and then pasting it into Div 2 using Ctl + V (text  is copied in div 2).
In the clipboard API, I want to get the HTML strip of element.

Comment: What version of clipboard?  Is it this one? https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/1.5.10/clipboard.min.js

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show us your code.